# How to avoid the rendering to the next page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm trying to download the CSV files it is rendering the next page, it should stay on the current page.

```
class EmployeeProofsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @employeeproofs = EmployeeProof.all.order('id  ASC')
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html {  render "employees/index", :layout => false }
         format.csv { send_data @employeeproofs.to_csv, :disposition => "attachment" }
      end
    end
end
```

Can any one tell me how to avoid the page rendering?

Comment: look at this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Comment: Post the link you are using to download

Comment: that i already done but still it is giving one new white page when i'm downloading, i need to be avoid that , if it is in same page also no problem. but should not go to other new page.

Comment: <%= link_to "Proof Data", employee_proofs_path(format: "csv") %>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **format.html** part from your code along with this add , **defaults: { format: :csv }** to your route used for this action.

Comment: try using  format.csv { send_data @data, :type => "application/vnd.ms-excel", :filename => "data.xls", :stream => false }